# Python value extraction without appending each value into a list

Tags: python

I'm curious if there's a much easier way to do this that I'm not familiar with.  Suppose this is in a networking context and I'm looking to extract values from a response.  These values are several numeric values delimited with pipes so for example |103|28|48|12|47|54|.  I'm currently using this.

```
rep_pipe = e_traffic.replace("|", "||")
extract_value = re.findall(r'\|([0-9]{2,3})\|', rep_pipe)
```

Which works absolutely fine if there's only a single value.  The reason it works fine with only a single instance of this string is because each value found between those pipes is appended to a list.  However when there are several of these strings in a response, they're all appended to the same list and there's noway to distinguish them from one another.

Suppose we have these following (decimal) values:

```
|101|102|103|110|111|
|94|81|48|32|103|120|
```

As it stands, this would come out as ['101', '102', '103', '110', '111', '94', '81', .. '120']

Is there a way to have these first converted to hex and then saved as the following:

```
['6566676E6F', '5E5130206778']
```

Might be important to note that these values appear at different offsets with different lengths, which makes it a little harder in my opinion.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single-character separator (`|` here) and want to process all the thus encoded data, you don't need regular expression matching to look for it. Instead, just split the string at the separator occurrences with the `.split()` method.

If you have multi-line textual data and want to process the lines individually, get them with the `.splitlines()` method.

So we have

```
lines = e_traffic.splitlines()
data = [line.split('|') for line in lines]
```

`data` will now be a nested list of strings:

```
[['', '101', '102', '103', '110', '111', ''], ['', '94', '81', '48', '32', '103', '120', '']]
```

You can convert the sequences of digits (which are still strings) to integers with the `int()` function:

```
int_data = [[int(s) for s in line if s] for line in data]
```

(The `if s` part of the inner list comprehension removes the empty strings for the leading and closing `|` on each line.)

This gives us a nice nested list of integers in `int_data`:

```
[[101, 102, 103, 110, 111], [94, 81, 48, 32, 103, 120]]
```

Sequences of integers can be converted to binary data with the `bytes()` function:

```
bin_data = [bytes(seq) for seq in int_data]
```

and finally, binary data can be converted to its hexadecimal representation (a string, once more) with the `.hex()` method of the `bytes` type:

```
hex_values = [b.hex() for b in bin_data]
```

We now have a list of strings in `hex_values`:

```
['6566676e6f', '5e5130206778']
```

#### Or, all the above in a single expression

```
hex_values = [
  bytes(
    int(n) for n in l.split('|') if n
  ).hex() for l in e_traffic.splitlines()
]
```

Or with the inner iteration in functional style:

```
hex_values = [
  bytes(
    map(int, filter(None, l.split('|')))
  ).hex() for l in e_traffic.splitlines()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string representations of integers into integers with the `int` function.

You can treat a sequence of small integers as a `bytes` value directly, and then hexlify that, or you can alternatively format each of the small integers with `'02X'` and then `join` them.

You can iterate over the matches without putting them in a list first with `finditer` instead of `findall`, but I'm not sure how much that buys you here.

Putting that all together:

```
extract_value = re.finditer(r'\|([0-9]{2,3})\|', rep_pipe)
buf = bytes(map(int, extract_value))
print(buf.hex())
```

But that only solves half of your problem. It looks like you want to handle each line as a separate string, but you're using a regex over the whole input. While you can make the regex and the postprocessing more complicated to deal with that, it's probably easier to just go a line at a time:

```
for line in rep_pipe:
    extract_value = re.findall(r'\|([0-9]{2,3})\|', line)
    buf = bytes(map(int, extract_value))
    print(buf.hex())
```